# Google Maps : NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError Angular

Tags: google-maps, angular7

I tried to include google map using `Angular 7`, I used `@agm/core` library for it.

I added API key in `app.module.ts` file

```
 AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
    apiKey : 'my_google_map_api'
 }),
```

Getting following error in console

```
Google Maps JavaScript API error: NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError
```

Comment: Here is a friendly reminder:

Angular 1.x  == AngularJS;
Angular 2+   == Angular

Answer (score 0):

The [NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#errorcodes) you're getting indicates that you're not using https://maps.googleapis.com to load the Maps JavaScript API.

You can use the following script from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API) for guidance in your Angular implementation:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Hope this helps!